# Abstract Factory for methods/constructor with different arguments

Tags: python, factory-method, abstract-factory

I have the following classes in my system (python):

```py
class Metric(ABC):
   def compute(self): -> float

class Visualization(ABC)
   def visualize(self)

class FirstMetric(Metric)
   def __init__(self, data1):
   def compute(self): -> float

class FirstVisualization(Visualization)
   def __init__(self, plot_param1, data1)
   def visualize(self)

class SecondMetric(Metric)
   def __init__(self, data1, data2):
   def compute(self): -> float

class SecondVisualization(Visualization)
   def __init__(self, plot_param1, plot_param2, data1, data2)
   def visualize(self)
```

I have one `Metric` and one `Visualization` subclass for each different implementation. As you can see in the code, each of those two classes require the same data, only visualization requires extra plotting parameters. When I instantiate them, I never instantiate objects from different catalogs, i.e, I would never create a `FirstMetric` and a `SecondVisualization` together.

Since I always generate pairs `Metric`-`Visualization`, and they have similar inputs, I was wondering if it would make sense to use the *Abstract Factory* design pattern. It would look like this:

```py
class AbstractFactory(ABC):
    def create_metric(self) -> Metric
    def create_visualization(self) -> Visualization

class FirstFactory(AbstractFactory):
    def __init__(self, data1, plot_param1):
        self.data1 = data1
        self.plot_param1 = plot_param1
    def create_metric(self):
        return FirstMetric(self.data1)
    def create_visualization(self):
        return FirstVisualization(self.data1, self.plot_param1)

class SecondFactory(AbstractFactory):
    def __init__(self, data1, data2, plot_param1, plot_param2):
        self.data1 = data1
        self.data2 = data2
        self.plot_param1 = plot_param1
        self.plot_param2 = plot_param2
    def create_metric(self):
        return SecondMetric(self.data1, self.data2)
    def create_visualization(self):
        return SecondVisualization(self.data1, self, data2, self.plot_param1, self.plot_param2)
```

I also wonder if this is "correct", since each `Metric` and `Visualization` subclass have different parameters in the constructor. Here, I am using the constructor of the `Factory` to solve this problem. All examples I have seen of *AbstractFactory* receive the parameters as arguments on the `create_...` methods, so maybe I am doing it wrong. Would you use this pattern here? If so, what would be the best implementation? If not, what would be a better solution?

Comment: "I also wonder if this is "correct", since each Metric and Visualization subclass have different parameters in the constructor" - that is perfectly fine/normal. You can also have your factory methods take in parameters if you want to (and are able to) supply some of them at product creation time (rather than at factory creation time). The abstract factory defines an interface for creating these objects - what that interface looks like is up to you; some of your parameters can be general, others factory-specific.

Comment: So in my case all factory methods would have no parameters (since they are defined at the subclass level), and I would supply all of them to the factory at factory creation time. I cannot supply them to the factory methods, because I would have to define them at the `AbstractFactory`. I understand that this is normal

Comment: I'm saying that's OK. You can design your factories in whatever way best suits your problem. There's no abstract factory police out there. In the original Design Patterns book, they show an example where they pass one parameter that came from the factory method, and an extra parameter that came from a private field of the factory itself. You can mix and match - based on how you intend to call the methods on the abstract factory instance, decide what to define on the `AbstractFactory` public interface, vs what to pass through concrete factory constructors or obtain in some other way.